Databricks Spark job running for long time with Executor loss reason as "worker decommissioned because of kill request from HTTP endpoint"
My spark job processes around 2.6GB(Approx).
Breakdown of the cluster configuration we are using to process the data:

Workers: The cluster consists of 2 to 25 worker nodes.
Memory: Each worker node has 128 to 1600 GB of memory.
Cores: Each worker node has 32 to 400 cores.
Driver: There is a single driver node.
Driver Memory: The driver node has 64 GB of memory.
Driver Cores: The driver node has 16 cores.
Runtime: The Spark runtime version is 12.2.x with Scala 2.12.

The job is running for long time with Executor getting decommissioned one after the other with error message as "worker decommissioned because of kill request from HTTP endpoint". Also, shuffle files are also getting lost.

24/06/07 10:19:12 ERROR CommandLineHelper$: Command [REDACTED] failed
with exit code 1 out: err:

As far as I observed in driver log4j logs, only execution of above command, the executors associated with the cluster started decommissioning.
I want to understand what has caused this scenario -Executor decommissioning?
Is it due to data -OOM? If so, the data is relatively small and should definitely be manageable for the configured cluster. So I believe data is not an issue here.
Found below ERROR log from the longing running executor:
Basically, we have been using the data mounted on ADLS using hive metastore through Thrift URL.

24/06/07 10:19:04 ERROR FuseLogAggregator: 2024/06/07 10:17:32.039685
dbr.ERROR Unable to setup backend: Volumes: &{/Volumes
uc-volumes:/Volumes {CseMetaFetching: S3FsImpl: AccessKeyId:
SecretAccessKey: SessionTokenId: CannedACL:{cannedAclHeader:}
RequesterPays: CredentialsType: CredentialsProvider: StsAssumeRoleArn:
StsAssumeRoleExternalId: StsEndpoint: AutoDetectEndpoint: Endpoint:
FallbackEndpoint: SseAlgorithm: SseKey: SseCAlgorithm: Cse:
CseMaterialProvider: OldAccessKeyId: OldSecretAccessKey:
OldStsAssumeRoleArn: OldStsAssumeRoleExternalId: OldStsEndpoint:
OldSseKey: OldSseKmsKeyId: OldSseCKey: OldCredentialsCustomClass:
AdlsOauth2ClientId: AdlsOauth2RefreshUrl: AdlsOauth2Credential:
AdlsOauth2TokenProvider: AdlsOauth2TokenProviderType:
AdlsOauth2TokenCustomProvider: AdlsOauth2RefreshToken: AdlsFsImpl:
AbfsAuthType: AbfsOauthProvider: AbfsOauth2ClientId:
AbfsOauth2ClientSecret: AbfsOauth2ClientEndpoint:
AbfsTokenProviderType: AbfsSasToken: GcpCredentialsType:
Attributes:map[]}}: Unrecognized storage scheme: uc-volumes

I would like to understand the root cause of the issue
We were using spot instances. As there might be chances that Spot instance may get evicted during the execution of the job, I tried using on-demand instances. But that approach was not helpful either.

As a sidenote, if you ever need to definitely check if a cluster is losing workers due to spot instance termination, you can go to the cluster details page in the UI, select the "Event Log" tab, and you may see event types that specify spot instance termination.

Have you tried updating the job's Databricks Runtime version to 14.3 LTS? And could you please share what data access mode you are using: Single User, Shared, No Isolation Shared?
